# Is there a way to prohibit users from removing only the first condition in the filter editor?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I'm trying to limit users from being able to remove the first filter in the filter editor. The user should be able to add and remove any other filter.

I've seen the section in the DevExpress documentation "Prohibit Users from Removing Condition" but this seems to apply to all filters in the filter editor rather then specific filters.

[image: filter image]

The image above shows the filter which I would like to not be removable. It would also need to be non-editable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out for myself. I ended up using a the `FixedFilter` property of the `GridControl` which lets you specify filters that do not show up in the `GridControl`'s filtering UI and cannot be edited.